# For Loop in Visual Basic results wrong number of loops

Tags: for-loop

I don't understand why I get x with a value of 6 while I think it should be 5.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim x = 0
    For x = 1 To 5
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Result: `6`

Comment: Hi Magda, welcome to StackOverflow! You should always provide the code that you have a question about in your question. While creating a question or answer there is a button at the top that will allow you to format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that `x` equals 6 is because of the nature of a loop. You put no code inside the body of the loop. If you printed your code there you would see

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Each time Next is reached, `x` is incremented. The fifth time you go through the loop, `x` is incremented to 6. In most cases it's best to not use loop variables outside of their loop. Using a C style loop what I mean is a bit more clear

```
for (int i=0; i<=5; i++){}
```

The loop runs until the condition `i <= 5` is not true. Since each time through the loop `i` is increased by 1 this occurs first when `i` equals 6.  I used the variable `i` here because `i` is a much more common loop variable name to see than `x`.

Comment: Thank you, it is very useful you explain